# Magento: Warning: simplexml_load_file

Tags: magento

i got a problem with magento. 
The problem is when i try to access: one of the categories
i get the following error:

**There has been an error processing your request**

Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.

Error log record number: 996553057356

**content of the log:**

> Warning: simplexml_load_file() [function.simplexml-load-file]:
>   /home/0/w202816/www/webshop/errors/local.xml:1: parser error :
>   Document is empty in
>   /home/0/w202816/www/webshop/errors/processor.php on line 337
>
> Warning: simplexml_load_file() [function.simplexml-load-file]: in
>   /home/0/w202816/www/webshop/errors/processor.php on line 337
>
> Warning: simplexml_load_file() [function.simplexml-load-file]: ^ in
>   /home/0/w202816/www/webshop/errors/processor.php on line 337
>
> Warning: simplexml_load_file() [function.simplexml-load-file]:
>   /home/0/w202816/www/webshop/errors/local.xml:1: parser error :
>   Start tag expected, '<' not found in
>   /home/0/w202816/www/webshop/errors/processor.php on line 337
>
> Warning: simplexml_load_file() [function.simplexml-load-file]: in
>   /home/0/w202816/www/webshop/errors/processor.php on line 337
>
> Warning: simplexml_load_file() [function.simplexml-load-file]: ^ in
>   /home/0/w202816/www/webshop/errors/processor.php on line 337
>
> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at
>   /home/0/w202816/www/webshop/errors/processor.php:337) in
>   /home/0/w202816/www/nwebshopikk/errors/processor.php on line 360
>
> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at
>   /home/0/w202816/www/webshop/errors/processor.php:337) in
>   /home/0/w202816/www/webshop/errors/processor.php on line 361

How to fix?

Comment: Without having access to your processor.php file that lists line numbers with errors above, I recommend this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Here is the content of the processor.php: http://pastebin.com/k9qjLeJK

Comment: The last two errors is due to that the header has already been returned or echoed so trying to return again displays such errors.I'm not sure but try once commenting out line 360 and 361 and reload.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I did that and it seems like two of the errors are gone. Any idea how to solve the rest?

Comment: @guru - Please do not add information to your question in a comment. You should edit your question, add the information, and then reply to the comment, using the `@` notation, and saying that you've edited your question.

Answer (score 1):

It appears you're missing the local.xml.sample or local.xml or its malformatted.

Try to find a vanilla magento installation and copy:

> root/errors/local.xml.sample

Into your

> root/errors/local.xml.sample
>   OR
>   root/errors/local.xml
>   If you want them rendered on the client.